# When returning a 401, nginx includes a cookie and turns off STS

Tags: cookies, nginx, uwsgi

My nginx config looks like:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;

    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate [removed];
    ssl_certificate_key [removed];

    include [removed];

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=[removed]";

    [various ssl settings removed]
}
```

The `include` directive has a `location @uwsgi` section with a `uwsgi_pass` specified.

Nothing in my application sets cookies.

- 200 responses show that Strict Transport Security (STS) is enabled (`Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=[removed]` is one of the response headers), and do not include cookies (I am not having uwsgi set any cookies).
- `GET` queries whose response code is 401 return do not have STS turned on and have a `Set-Cookie` header:

  `Set-Cookie:session=[removed]; HttpOnly; Path=[removed]`
- 502 responses do not have an STS header, but also don't have a cookie header.

Software versions: nginx 1.4.6; uwsgi 2.0.6

OS: Ubuntu server

Comment: Lack of STS is simple. By default nginx don't add headers to 4xx/5xx responses.  Since nginx 1.7.5 you could use `always` flag. `add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=1000" always;`

Comment: your `[removed]` don't hide anything sensitive and just add noise.

Comment: I'm guess, that cookies are set by your backend.

Comment: Can't do anything about the [removed], it's a compliance thing, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, `always` did it. What's less clear is whether *not* setting `always` could lead to a situation in which someone could conduct an MITM attack / actually subvert STS.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how lack of STS header on error page could lead to that situation. Just to remind, STS header is only works on https connection, so to revert STS one should already have valid cert for you domain, and in that case lack of STS is least of your problems…